# Matrix equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am doing an introduction course in MATLAB (I am a beginner) and I'm having trouble solving an issue regarding an equation of matrices.

The equation is

```
AX = C - BX
```

I want to solve for the matrix `X`. No matter how I have tried to solve it I come up either empty handed or with some sort of a syntax error. I think I am missing something fundamental.

Any help on the subject is very much appreciated.

Comment: It would be best if you posted your code along with the error you are getting

Answer (score 2):

For this equation to be consistent, `A` and `B` *must* have the same size. Therefore, you can re-write your equation as:

```
(A+B)X = C
```

This can be solved in MATLAB with:

```
X = (A+B)\C
```

Note that this will *always* find a solution, regardless of the size of `A+B`:

- If `A+B` is square, you'll find "the" solution.
- if `A+B` is over/underdetermined, it will return a least-squares approximation to `X`.

It's up to you to decide whether this is desirable or not.

In case `C` is zero, you might want to use `null` (or look at `svd`).

Comment: @B... for an exact solution `A` and `B` should be square, but you can search for a least-square solution when `A` and `B` has more rows than columns.

Comment: @B...: Suppose `A = n×m` and `X = m×p`, then `AX = n×p`. That means `C` must be `n×p` as well, and so `B` must be `n×m`. There's no limitation on the values of `n`, `m` and `p` as far as I can see...

Comment: Regardless of the number of rows and columns , `X = (A+B)\C` will find a solution. Of course it is goot to know this may not be 'the' solution.

Comment: @Shai Ah that's what you mean. Editing...